# CodeIgniter email error

Tags: email, codeigniter, load

I use codeigniter to send email
but i have this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in /home/brokarsi/public_html/test/system/libraries/Email.php on line 1922
```

what is this error?

Comment: given most SO users aren't psychic, please post some code ~

Answer (score 2):

In my version of CodeIgniter (1.7.2) this corresponds to the following line :

```
$CI->lang->load('email');
```

I would guess the problem is that the Language library is not loaded but is required by the Email library.  Could you try auto-loading the Language library?

**system/application/config/autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array(...., 'language');
```